# Grails 2.3 unittesting with IVY resolver

Tags: unit-testing, maven, grails, ivy, spock

If I do `create-app` with grails 2.3, create a simple spock unit-test, and change the configuration en grails to use ivy resolver:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy" // or maven
```

The unit test crashes with the following error:

```
| Running without daemon...
| Running 1 unit test...
| Running 1 unit test... 1 of 1
| Error Error running unit tests: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
        ... 7 more
| Error Error running unit tests: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
| Running 1 unit test....
| Running 1 unit test.....
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in C:\ivytry\foobar\target\test-reports
```

Any ideas how to get around this? The reason why we need to use Ivy is that Maven doesn't seem to support custom remote repositories, where I need to specify username/password. -Besides in buildconfig, but I don't want my credentials under source control :)

**EDIT (Solved):**  See comments!

Comment: Thumb rule in Grails 2.3.0 :- run `dependency-report` to see if there is any conflict.

Comment: There are some. But none related to testing - at least not that I can figure out..Hamcrest doesn't appear in dependency report. But this means, that testing does not work OOTB with Grails 2.3 and ivy resolver? Seems weird!

Comment: I can see `hamcrest` in test report on a sample grails 2.3 app with ivy resolver. Generally, it is bundled in spock (default test f/w in 2.3), but I do not see spock in your usage. You get a `NoClassDefFoundError` which means you have hamcrest available but it is getting conflicted by something else. Show `BuildConfig`.

Comment: Buildconfig is default. Didn't change a thing from "create-app". The only thing that is changed is the dependency resolver... I haven't got it right here, however the above should be sufficient.

Comment: If BuildConfig is default, then `create-unit-test` or `create-integration-test` should have created a spock spec instead of a JUnit test. Can you create a spock specification and try to test the same.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear - it is a spock unit-test. That is, a test that ends with "spec" and extends Specification.,

Comment: An I run the app using `grails test-app unit:`

Comment: Try with `grails test-app` or `grails test-app :spock`.

Comment: No luck with that either!

Comment: The issue was because of the "infamous" intellij fix with idea 12 and grails 2.3 - restoring the "sources" and "javadoc" jar files, fixes the issue!

Comment: @Hoof add the answer as a normal post (not as comment) and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of the "infamous" intellij fix with idea 12 and grails 2.3 - restoring the "sources" and "javadoc" jar files, fixes the issue!